# How to calculate time complexity of nested loop?

Tags: python, time-complexity, coding-efficiency

I am having trouble calculating time complexities, especially with while loops:

example 1:

```
while self.rotors == []:
      for i in range(3):
          rotor = input("Choose rotor {}: ".format(i + 1))
          while rotor not in range(1, 6):
                print("\nInvalid. You can only choose from 1 to 5 rotors.")
```

will the time complexity be O(n x 3 x r) or O(3)?

example 2:

```
for i in range(3):
    start = input("Enter the starting point of rotor {}: ".format(i + 1))
    while start not in self.rotors[i]:
          print("\nEnter one alphabet character or a number form 0-9 ONLY.")
```

will the time complexity be O(3 x n) or O(3)?

Comment: you never modify self.rotors in either loop.  is that intentional?

Comment: What is `r`? What is `n`? Also, since constant factors don't affect the result, `O(1)` is conventionally used for anything that is independent of the input size, regardless of what the actual constant might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to note about time complexity is that the variables are typically related to the data/input in some way. Because you are getting the input within the loop, there is no time complexity here in the typical sense.
In addition, consider the state of example 2. If start is not in self.rotors, the while will always evaluate to true so this has worst case O(infinity).

Time complexity is usually evaluated assuming a constant input, as a function that doesnt get any input other than the arguments. If the conditions for breaking are ever dependent on the user *within the loop*, time complexity is no longer a useful metric.

One final note is that you drop constants when calculating time complexity, so there will never be a number in your big O.

Comment: what if i have a `while list[0] != "E":` (this while loop rotates the list until E is in index 0, by appending the last popped item), so I'll assume the worst case is for "E" to be in index 1. Therefore, the time complexity will be O(n), where n is the length of the list, right?

Comment: Exactly! Whenever you iterate over a list that doesnt change, you can expect it to be O(n)

Answer (score 3):

a few notes that might help you out:

- time complexity calculation assumes N is approaching infinity, meaning constant are irrelevant. in your case O(n) is the same as O(3n).
- when talking about loops, you can multiply the time complexity in the loop length. in your case, iterating from 0 to 3 gives you *3 factor. the while loop is potentially infinite (assuming an adversary or just bad luck) since the user might continuously enter input that will not reach stop condition. If the user gives total of N inputs , each one is << than Nthan you have O(3n) which is the same as O(n)
- time complexity check how much time your program takes, specifically here - how many commands. command can be an ambiguous phrase - is it an atomic CPU command? assembly command? a python command? this depends on your setting